# how to use explode function in ci?

Tags: codeigniter

code:

```
<?php
    $courses = ',BTech,MTech,PHD-Sci,PHD-Engg,';
    $course = explode(",", $courses);
    foreach ($course as $rows) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('course_master');
        $where = "course_short_name = '".$row['courses']."'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
?>
```

output:

[image]

I am new in ci. In this code I am use explode function and want to run query like select * from course_master where course_short_name = ',BTech,'select * from course_master where course_short_name = ',MTech,' like this. So, How can I do this ?please help.

Thank You

Comment: can anybdy answer me plss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be a work in progress...

**1st Item:** The Explode. Its simple PHP

When you are unsure about something - play with it ( the code ) and see what you get. i.e.

```
     $courses = 'BTech,MTech,PHD-Sci,PHD-Engg';
     $course = explode(",", $courses);
// DEBUG - What am I actually Getting before I 
// unleash this upon the rest of my code...
     var_dump($course);
```

This will generate an array as you have expected...

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'BTech' (length=5)
  1 => string 'MTech' (length=5)
  2 => string 'PHD-Sci' (length=7)
  3 => string 'PHD-Engg' (length=8)
```

Note my $courses list isn't laced with leading and trailing . (commas) like yours and no idea why...

**2nd Item:** With this multiple select in a loop, how do you intend to use the results?

So the question is - what is it your are expecting as your image with the multiple selects aint it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$courses = ',BTech,MTech,PHD-Sci,PHD-Engg,';
$course = explode(",", $courses);
foreach ($course as $rows) 
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('course_master');
    $this->db->where("course_short_name", $rows);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty simple to do this thing, by just counting your array length here is the example

```
<?php
    $courses = 'BTech,MTech,PHD-Sci,PHD-Engg';
    $course = explode(",", $courses);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($course);$i++) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('course_master');
        $where = "course_short_name = '".$course[$i]."'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
?>
```

Here you need to remove ',' from the starting and the ending of the $courses, otherwise explode will generate two empty elements in array.

Here $course[$i] will take each element turn by turn so your query will run for the each element available in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use single select with 'or_where' condition

```
<?php

    $courses = array('BTech','MTech','PHD-Sci','PHD-Engg');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('course_master');
    foreach ($courses as $rows) 
    {
        $this->db->or_where('course_short_name',$rows);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query->array_result();

?>
```